# What are the downsides to using Github Pages?

Tags: web-hosting, github

I'm considering hosting our new marketing website for a software product using [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/). The website will be quite small, and we expect low amounts of traffic. We've been using shared hosting (like HostMonster) in the past, but the ability to simply push your git changes to Github to publish changes is very appealing. Of course, Github pages is free so I imagine there has to be downsides.

If I switch to using Github Pages instead of traditional shared hosting, what am I missing out on (other than the fact that the site must be static)? Are they less reliable?

In my situation, the site I want to host is a marketing site for a software application that we are hosting on Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is opinion-based but I'd still like to help you out here.

Advantages:

- Well, it's free!
- GitHub's CMS
- gzip & minify
- A fast CDN

Disadvantages:

- No 'good' cache
- No 'good' SSL support
- No good cookies system

> Of course, Github pages is free so I imagine there has to be downsides.

I understand you're thinking that but GitHub pages is quite reliable and fast. I could say it's almost as good as shared hosting but not with the features.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't find anything negative about it when searching online. I'm glad to see that the disadvantages you list don't matter much to me.

Comment: @Tanner Great! I have never had any issues with GitHub pages (**any**), so I can really recommend it to you. Good luck with your product.

Comment: For future visitors and maybe the OP, a handy guide about using GitHub pages is: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/